# Erlang shell from a browser?

Tags: javascript, erlang

I have an erlang app with a web frontend. Right now, if you want to talk to it via the shell, you have to do it from the command line. This app will be running on multiple platforms and in environments where the administrator may not be very command-line savvy, but for tech support purposes I'd like to be able to have them bring up a shell in their browser and be able to inspect the state of the node from that.

Has someone already implemented such a thing? It would need to support Windows, Red Hat, and OS X, as well as major browsers. Something that looked a lot like the shell and supported the same commands would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just run into the [erlwsh](https://github.com/killme2008/erlwsh) project. Does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility could be to use a web based terminal such as [AjaxTerm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/) and to set the Erlang shell as the default shell for the web user. For example, in a UNIX system, this could be done by setting the proper value in the /etc/passwd file.

Obviously, we're considering here a secure environment, in which access is not provided to any malicious user and the nodes are not accessible from the outside world.

Comment: Ajaxterm looks interesting, and if we had any dependency at all on Python already I'd seriously consider using it as-is. However, the server side is *tiny* if you don't count the web server, so it looks like it'd be straightforward to port it to Erlang/Mochiweb. Adding authentication would be easy.

Thanks for your answer!